# Multiple image uploads through file upload and saving to database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Okay, so I'm trying to select multiple images and save them in a database in asp.net.
I don't want to use any plugins or any kind of scripts.

This is the designer page:

```
<asp:FileUpload AllowMultiple="true"  ID="fileuploadimages" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" CssClass="btnStyle" Text="Upload Image"
 OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
```

I have done this so far on the button upload event. What it does is that it allows me to select more than one file, like if I select 3 images, it saves the first file thrice in my database and saves it once in the folder "Pictures" instead of saving all three.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileuploadimages.HasFile == false)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('No File Uploaded.')</script>", false);
    }
    else    
    {
        foreach (var file in fileuploadimages.PostedFiles)
        {
            string filename =Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);

            fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Pictures/" + filename));  

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into
            EventPageView(Event_name,Event_Text,Image_Path)
            values(@EventName,@EventText,@ImagePath)", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", filename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventName", txtEventName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventText", txtEnterDesc.Text);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
            BindDataList();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: just remove some extra codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change those two lines line:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);

fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Pictures/" + filename));
```

to

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Pictures/" + filename));
```

I hope it will help. Because you must use the object `file`